# Android - Add views to LinearLayout with they are evenly distributed

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Trying to add several views to a LinearLayout by `addView()`.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams 
   = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
         ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
```

I have tested different settings to the `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` but have no luck.

Since the views are dynamic, they have to be added programmatically.

**UPDATE**

[image]
I expect the 4 views are filled the full width of screen, but they are now on the left side

Comment: Mention the problem you are facing.

Comment: Using weights ?

Comment: Can you please explain your issue in detail? It is not clear what you need here

Comment: In your layoutparams third parameter is used for weight. If you want to use weight then the dimensions of layout should be 0 dp as per linearlayout orientation. Before that share screenshot what do you want to achieve and how are you getting after using this code?

Comment: Change code from `LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams 
   = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
         ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);` to `LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams 
   = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
         ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);` @KoneMan

Comment: assign weights of eact view to 1 and set width to 0dp for each views than add it to linear layout.

Comment: @Piyush Your answer is so right and solved the problem! I have tried the same parameters as yours, but with `LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams`. That makes those 4 views not in the screen.